# Search Gmail for emails with no text (except for signature)

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I want to create a Gmail filter that uses the *Canned Responses* labs feature to automatically send a reply to messages that have no text in the body, apart from any signatures. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible, since <strike>there is no option to send reply to emails using a filter and</strike> you can't really search for something that contains a signature, which could be anything.

Comment: There _is_ actually an option to reply with a filter, it just needs to be activated in the labs settings first. Also, Gmail greys out signatures in emails, so there must be a search command of some sort that checks this.

Comment: @adam can you please share that lab feature ?

Comment: @shahjapan Go to the cog icon and mail settings and open the labs tab. Then do a find in page for Canned Responses.